# Sql Azure Connection String error

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to Sql Azure use the ADO.net connection still provided by the portal. It is of the format

var connectionstring =

"Server=tcp:abcdefghij.database.windows.net,1433;Database=[myDatabase];User ID=[myName]@abcdefghij;Password=[]myPassWord;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"

When I pass this connection string to the DbContext constructor it falls over. The error message is

"The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.TypeExtensions' threw an exception."

Any ideas what the problem can be?

Thanks

Martin

Comment: Well one thing jumps out at me immediately. abcdefghij.database.windows.net,1433 should be abcdefghij.database.windows.net:1433

Comment: Adding entity framework tag since it's most likely you need to pass in something specific for the entity framework. The connection string should be good for using it directly with ADO.NET.